# Background image stretch for QWidget Screen

Tags: qt

Is it possible to stretch the background image. 
Actually I have a image of size 320X480, I want to use this image as background for a QWidget screen with size 360X640.

I tried with the followings:

1). Here the image gets stretched for the screen  but a button with another image is loaded along with the Main screen image:

```
ui->MainScreen->setStyleSheet("border-image: url(:/images/Main-screen.png);");
```

2). Here the image is not stretched, but displayed as tiles:

```
ui->MainScreen->setStyleSheet("background-image: url(:/images/Main-screen.png); border: none");
ui->MainScreen->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Preferred));
ui->MainScreen->setBackgroundRole(QPalette::Background);
```

Any suggestions for this....!

Thanks...

Comment: with your first solution, what do you mean by 'a button with another image is loaded' ? I don't see the link between the background image you are setting with a style sheet and another button. And please, if you want others to help, accept answers to your previous questions !

Comment: Actually in the Main screen I have a button with a image. If I use "border-image", then the Main screen image also loaded in the Button along with the actual image of the button. So as such 2 images loaded in the Button. I hope You got the issue now!

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason that your button is getting the same image as the background is because style sheets are applied to child widgets too (I think). After doing the same code you used in #1, try setting the button's style sheet to something else. The child's style sheet should override the parent's style sheet.

Comment: yes, I am setting the button style sheet differently like:                                                                        ui->StartpushButton->setIcon(QIcon(":/images/Main-screen_button.png"));
//ui->StartpushButton->setStyleSheet("image: url(:/images/iPhone_Main-screen_button.png); border: none");
ui->StartpushButton->setStyleSheet("background: transparent; border: none");                                                                         But the result is as said in #1.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
ui->MainScreen->setStyleSheet("QMainWindow {border-image: url(:/images/Main-screen.png);}");
```

This tells Qt to change the background image of all of the QMainWindows in the child tree. from ui->MainScreen. If you do not specify the class type or object name, no filter will be applied, and every child will get the background image.

Answer (score 1):

```
QWidget#QMainWindow { style; }
```

`#subclass` after `mainclass` (`QWidget`) sets style to JUST the subclass

It will do exactly what your trying to do.